# How to create q-radio input with multiple different models dynamically

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using the quasar framework with VueJS 3 Composition API,
I am receiving some responses from an API and according to the API I am trying to generate some checkboxes and radio input dynamically. I generated the `q-checkbox` element but I am facing an issue with `q-radio` because I have to have multiple radio groups with multiple options. so please guide me on how can I achieve this.

Here is the snippet of code that I tried so far.

**Html template part**

```js
<q-item
  disable
  tag="label"
  v-ripple
  v-for="(item, index1) in optGroup.optionsItem"
  :key="index1"
>
  <q-item-section avatar>
    <q-radio
      v-model="selectedVariantIds[index]"
      :val="item.id"
      color="primary"
      v-if="optGroup.option_type == 'radio'"
    />
    <q-checkbox
      v-model="selectedAddonIds"
      :disabled="
        optGroup.max_select != 0 &&
        selectedAddonIds.length >= optGroup.max_select
      "
      :val="item.id"
      color="primary"
      v-if="optGroup.option_type == 'checkbox'"
    />
  </q-item-section>
  <q-item-section>
    <q-item-label lines="1" class="pc font-regular fs-16">{{
      item.option_item_name
    }}</q-item-label>
    <q-item-label caption class="sc font-regular fs-14"
      >{{ item.currency_symbol != "" ? item.currency_symbol : "$"
      }}{{ item.option_sale_price }}</q-item-label
    >
  </q-item-section>
</q-item>
```

**Script**

```js
const selectedAddonIds = ref([]);
const selectedVariantIds = ref([]);
```

I am able to get the selected Addons as array after checking some checkboxes but the problem is with the variants as they are the radio input it is giving the single value even the radio input is from a different group.

Comment: You should use the same `index1` variable when specifying the `v-model` for the radio-buttons. But your data model does not look good. IF these are questions in a survey - then questions of type "multi-choice and multi-answer" must have an array of choices (each choise of type Boolean) while questions of type "multi-choice and single answer" must have an object with 2 properties - one property as array of the values and the other property as a `v-model` for the chosen value.